# Decode nested jsons swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

Hello people I have a little question related with the Encodable protocol in Swift.

I have the following json file:

```
let magicJson = """
{
    "value": [
        {
        "scheduleId": "magic@yahoo.com",
        "somethingEventMoreMagical": "000220000"
        }
    ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

For decoding I tried to avoid having to create two objects that both go with Decodable, and the first one has an array of the second object. I would like to flatten that object into something like this:

```
struct MagicalStruct: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case value
    }
    
    private enum ScheduleCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case roomEmail = "scheduleId"
    }
    
    let roomEmail: String
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let magicContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ScheduleCodingKeys.self, forKey: .value)
        roomEmail = try magicContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: ScheduleCodingKeys.roomEmail)
    }
}
```

However when I try the following code: `JSONDecoder().decode(MagicalStruct.self, magicJson)` I get that it expects an array but gets a dictionary. On the other hand when I go with `JSONDecoder().decode([MagicalStruct].self, magicJson)`, I get that it receives an array but expects a dictionary.

Does anyone know why this is happening ?

Comment: You don't seem to have `scheduleId` key in your input JSON.

Comment: I edited wrong the json, it was scheduleId in it as well, let me edit :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First when you're decoding your struct using:

```
JSONDecoder().decode(MagicalStruct.self, magicJson)
```

you're trying to extract a **single** object: `let roomEmail: String`.

However, your input JSON contains an array of objects with emails. Which means your code:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let magicContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ScheduleCodingKeys.self, forKey: .value)
    roomEmail = try magicContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: ScheduleCodingKeys.roomEmail)
}
```

tries to decode a single email and there is a collection instead (in your example with *one* element - that's why it may be confusing).

Also your error `Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead` is on the line:

```
let magicContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ScheduleCodingKeys.self, forKey: .value)
```

You need to decode an array:

```
var magicContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .value)
```

But then you have an array of objects with `scheduleId` and `somethingEventMoreMagical`  keys. How do you want to assign all the values to your one `let roomEmail: String` variable?

---

You can decode a dictionary instead:

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: [MagicalStruct]].self, from: magicJson)

print(result["value"]!) // prints [MagicalStruct(roomEmail: "magic@yahoo.com")]
```

And you can simplify your `MagicalStruct`:

```
struct MagicalStruct: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case roomEmail = "scheduleId"
    }

    let roomEmail: String
}
```

Comment: Hey:) Thank you for your answer, this is indeed a nice solution, but what I was looking for, is not a direct direction/solution, but rather why Swift doesn't allow what I describe above with Decodable. If you have any idea, feel free to answer I would be very happy to hear more opinions/solutions :)

Comment: @VladSima I updated my answer with a better explanation. Basically all your problems occur because you try to parse an array to a single object. You need to choose what do you want: return an array of [MagicalStruct], make `let roomEmail: String` an array instead of String or just parse the *first* email from the array.